# What are the Supabase Edge Functions Memory Limits

Tags: function, out-of-memory, deno, supabase

I created a Supabase Deno Edge Function that works perfectly well inside the Supabase Docker environment on my Mac, but whenever I execute it in production / the cloud I run into this error after a couple of seconds of execution time:

```
502: Bad Gateway (DEPLOYMENT_FAILED)

The deployment failed while serving the request.
```

My guess is that I'm running into a memory limit. According to my local logs (Supabase doesn't seem to get the logs when I run it on their infra) **my script needs around a 150 MB in memory**.

Does anyone here know **what the production memory limits** are for Supabase functions?

I can't find anything about that in the docs nor on the pricing page.

The file size of my script is 33 KB when I bundle the function via `deno bunlde`, so it shouldn't be the script size limit, that's why I'm guessing it's a memory issue.

Comment: This page details the limits: https://deno.com/deploy/docs/pricing-and-limits

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but that's the documentation from Deno not Supabase (their limits differ, e.g. you can run a function for 1000ms compared to 50ms on Deno)

Comment: I asked on the official Supabase Discord server, and was informed by one of the team members (_silentworks_: Discord ID `107176742342402048`) that Supabase uses Deno Deploy, and its limits are derived from those at the link I shared with you.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is around 500 MB right now.

You can view the limits at https://deno.com/deploy/docs/pricing-and-limits.